# How can i multiply the prime numbers of a number from user input and display it in C language

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, printf, primes

So I started learning C language for Uni and got stuck with this exercise, I found a way to ge the prime numbers of a number but I don't know how to multiply the prime numbers and display them.

```c
int main()
 {

    int number;
    int prime;
    int i,j;
    

    
    printf("Insert number:");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    
    printf("Prime numbers of %d are: ",number);



        for(i = 2; i <= number; i++)
        {
            prime = 1;

            for(j = 2; j <= i/2; j++)
            {
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    prime = 0;
                }
            }
            if(prime == 1)
            {
                printf(" %d", i);
            }
        }



    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What are "prime numbers of a number"? Do you mean prime factors?

Comment: The code suggests that you are looking for primes up to the given number, though. So what is the question? If you have the numbers, why can't you multiply them?

Comment: e.g Input is 15 , the output is 2 3 5 7 11 13 , and i need to multiply this numbers

Comment: You've got 2 basic ways to go.  You can store each prime factor in some data structure as you find them and them multiply them at the end.  Or you can start with a value set to 1, and then multiple it each time you find a factor.  On input 8, do you want to count the 2 three times and expect to get 8 out after you multiply?

Comment: If you're multiplying the resulting primes, you need multiplication in your code. You currently have none. A running product accumulator, initially 1, would suffice.

Comment: @WhozCraig that's what i am trying to do , how do i implement that multiplication?

Comment: You use one of the [language operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) that perform multiplication. What is the name of the language book/text you're learning C from? Operator usage should be covered abusively within.

Comment: The code does not find the prime factors of the value entered (it finds prime numbers up to that value). So you have nothing to multiply. But if the intention is to find the product of all those prime numbers, then multiply a running product by each prime found. `if(prime) { printf(" %d", i); product *= i; }` Remember when you reach `29` the product will overflow 32-bit `int`.

Comment: ..and a 64-bit product will overflow at prime `53`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce one more variable that will store the nultiplication of prime numbers.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int number;

    printf( "Insert number (0 - exit ): " );

    if ( scanf( "%u", &number ) == 1 && number != 0 )
    {
        if ( number < 2 )
        {
            printf( "There are no prime numbers in the range [0, %u].\n", number );
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned long long product = 2;
    
            printf( "Prime numbers in the range [0, %u] are: ", number );

            printf( "%u ", 2 );
            for ( unsigned int i = 3; i <= number; i += 2 )
            {
                int prime = 1;

                for( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j <= i / j; j += 2 )
                {
                    if ( i % j == 0 )
                    {
                        prime = 0;
                    }
                }

                if ( prime )
                {
                    printf( "%d ", i );
                    product *= i;
                }
            }

            printf( "\nTheir multiplication is equal to %llu\n", product );   
        }
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Insert number (0 - exit ): 10
Prime numbers in the range [0, 10] are: 2 3 5 7 
Their multiplication is equal to 210
```